# Ошибка в рассылке Python Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='next', state=bot_mailing.state, chat_id=admin)
async def sendall(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    users = db.get_users()
    data = await state.get_data()
    text = data.get('text')
    await state.finish()
    for row in users:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(row[0], text=text)
            await sleep(0.33)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(str(e))

    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="Успешная Рассылка")
```

в консоли ошибка:

```
await bot.send_message(row[0], text=text)
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 339, in send_message
  result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 231, in request
  return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
  return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
  exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
  raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound: Chat not found
```

рассылка приходит всем, но ошибка в консоли...

Comment: Значит какой-то чат с ботом удален. Делайте try/except и удаляйте чат из бд.